# Cutting date from a file

Tags: grep, cron

Right now, I have a cron job that looks like this:

```
*/15 * * * * cp /home/server/server_log.txt /var/www/html/logs/`date "+\%d-\%b.txt"` >/dev/null 2>&1
```

It works perfectly.

However, I want to modify it to only get data from /home/server/server_log.txt for today's date, whilst still copying it to the same location with the date preserved like it is above.

The date in that file is formatted like so:

```
01/11/2020 14:54:26 text
02/11/2020 03:22:05 text
03/11/2020 09:18:48 test
```

I figured this might be possible with grep, but am not sure what the syntax would be.

Comment: There are many available options to rotate logs (`logrotate`, `multilog`, `newsyslog` for BSDs, etc). As @Jos already answered, it can be done via `cron` with some `grep`ping and `cp`ing, as you have figured out, but I think you may be reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command would be something like

```
grep "$(date +'%d/%m/%Y')" server_log.txt
```

where

```
date +'%d/%m/%Y'
```

generates todays date in the given format, i.e. `06/11/2020`.